# spring hibernate configuration using resource_local or jta by default?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, persistence, jta

may i know as my configuration is done directly on applicationContext.xml, i do not have persistence.xml .  by default this is resource_loca or jta?  do i need to add extra parameter if i want to use jta?

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
        </property>
            <!-- xdb is defined by running the hsqldb as xdb (see above) -->
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@theserver:1521:appsdb</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>test</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>test</value>
        </property>
    </bean>




<bean id="annotatedsessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">


    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.x.model" >
    </property>


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                  com.company.x.services.ExternalEhCacheProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>



        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RESOURCE_LOCAL` only applies to JPA `EntityManager`, not to a Hibernate `SessionFactory`. Hibernate's Spring integration is rather smoother than it is with JPA, and so the only thing that determines the transactional behaviour is which transaction manager you use with it (either `HibernateTransactionManager` or `JtaTransactionManager`). It'll work with either one without you having to explicitly configure the `SessionFactory`.